# Redis-To-Go difficulty - getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I've followed the commands of installing Redis To Go, including adding the gem, adding this line `ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://username:password@my.host:6389'` to config/environments/development.rb, and adding

`uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])`

to `config/initializers/redis.rb`.

I'm getting the following error message when I try to test in my console with `REDIS.set("foo", "bar")` :

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really added this line

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://username:password@my.host:6389'
```

No need to look further, that's where the error came from. Go to your [RedisToGo dashboard](https://redistogo.com/instances?language=en) and copy/paste the connection string (displayed at the top-right corner once you clicked on one of your redis instance) from there your `REDISTOGO_URL` should be something like:

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://redistogo:ababab24160696ddd975c7012343432@grideye.redistogo.com:10400/'`
```